# A question about sets that disconnect Euclidean space or Hilbert space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a separable and infinite dimensional Hilbert space or else a finite dimensional Euclidean space having dimension at least two. Let $C$ be any proper subset of $X$ such that $X \setminus C$ is not connected. Must $C$ always have at least one connected component that is not a singleton?

Comment: So you're asking whether a totally disconnected $C$ can disconnect $X$?

Comment: You seem to have asked this before? http://mathoverflow.net/a/36884/2060